# Make a httpx GET request with data body

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, httpx

When I do a curl request for GET endpoint of a REST API, I would go it like this

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8000/user/?limit=10' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[
  {
    "item_type": "user",
    "skip": 0
  }
]'
```

Directly translated into `requests`, I would get

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = {
    'limit': '10'
}

json_data = [
    {
        'item_type': 'user',
        'skip': 0,
    },
]

response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/user/', params=params, headers=headers, json=json_data)

# Note: json_data will not be serialized by requests
# exactly as it was in the original request.
#data = '[\n  {\n    "item_type": "document",\n    "skip": 0\n  }\n]'
#response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/user/', params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Now for my test environment I am going to use `httpx`'s `AsyncClient`, but I cannot find a way to use the data part, i.e., `[{"item_type": "user", "skip": 0}]`, in a get request.

It would be terrific, if you know how to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [httpx docs](https://www.python-httpx.org/compatibility/#request-body-on-http-methods), `.get` doesn't support request bodies. It suggests you use the more generic `.request` function instead.

> The HTTP GET, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS methods are specified as not supporting a request body. To stay in line with this, the .get, .delete, .head and .options functions do not support content, files, data, or json arguments.

```py
# possible alternative
httpx.request(
  method="GET",
  url="https://www.example.com/",
  content=b'A request body on a GET request.'
)
```

Important note: the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-get) states clients should not use body content with `GET` requests and if they do, there's no guarantee that it will show up at the server (as intermediaries are allowed to strip it off):

> Although request message framing is independent of the method used, content received in a GET request has no generally defined semantics, cannot alter the meaning or target of the request, and might lead some implementations to reject the request and close the connection because of its potential as a request smuggling attack (Section 11.2 of [HTTP/1.1]). A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a GET request unless it is made directly to an origin server that has previously indicated, in or out of band, that such a request has a purpose and will be adequately supported. An origin server SHOULD NOT rely on private agreements to receive content, since participants in HTTP communication are often unaware of intermediaries along the request chain

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. So you would suggest to make it without a body in the GET request?

Comment: Yes. Pass any parameters you wish to communicate to the REST API in the query string of the URL.